# matlab uicontrol radiobutton issue

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, uicontrol

I have a 2d plot (hhh handle) done with imagesc to which I want to add a line if a radiobutton is pressed, and remove the same lien if the push button is released.

When the pushbutton is pressed the line shows OK, however if the pushbutton is released there is this error:

Undefined function or variable 'Hline'

Lokks line the program can´t remember the Hline value even it is being updated with guidata. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Here is the function

```
function  abc(x)
% x is a m x n matrix
hhh=imagesc(x)

% now a pushbutton to put or remove a line in the above plot

uicontrol('Style','radiobutton','String','put_remove_line',...
    'units','normalized','pos', [tf_left 0 .1/2 1/25],'parent',hhh,'HandleVisibility','on', 'fontSize',6,'Callback',{@put_remove_line ,delta_f_line, hhh ,Hline});

end % end abc function
%radiobutton callback function

function put_remove_line(hObject,event,delta_f_line,hhh,Hline)

        a=get(hObject,'Value');
        if a % if button is pressed a 
                axes(hhh)
                xlimits=get(gca,'XLim');
                Hline.xxx=line(xlimits,[delta_f_line], 'LineStyle',':','LineWidth',2);

        else
            delete(Hline.xxx,)
        end
guidata(hObject,Hline)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#br7qvh9) for callbacks:

> If you define additional input arguments, then the values you pass to
>   the callback must exist in the workspace when the end user triggers
>   the callback.

As written, your function will only pass the value of Hline as it exists in the scope of abc(x) when `uicontrol()` is executed. You're receiving an error because it is not defined, hence `Undefined function or variable 'Hline'`. To solve the problem, instead use your existing `guidata` storage method to retrieve Hline at the beginning of `put_remove_line()`.

Assuming Hline is stored in your `guidata`:

```
function  abc(x)
% x is a m x n matrix
hhh = figure
hhh2 = imagesc(x)

% now a pushbutton to put or remove a line in the above plot

uicontrol('Style','radiobutton','String','put_remove_line',...
    'units','normalized','pos', [tf_left 0 .1/2 1/25],'parent',hhh,'HandleVisibility','on', 'fontSize',6,'Callback',{@put_remove_line ,delta_f_line, hhh});

end % end abc function
%radiobutton callback function

function put_remove_line(hObject,event,delta_f_line,hhh)

        Hline = guidata(hObject)
        a=get(hObject,'Value');
        if a % if button is pressed a 
                axes(hhh)
                xlimits=get(gca,'XLim');
                Hline.xxx=line(xlimits,[delta_f_line], 'LineStyle',':','LineWidth',2);

        else
            delete(Hline.xxx)
        end
guidata(hObject,Hline)
end
```

EDIT: I just realized something else about your code. Once you resolve the Hline error, you're going to get another error:

```
Error using uicontrol
An object of class uicontrol, can not be a child of class image.
```

This is because you're defining hhh as an image, which cannot have children. I've made another modification to the code to resolve the error, which is just to open a figure window to serve as the parent object.

Comment: Many many thanks, i will see this over, for the time being we have used global xxx which looks like not the best solution...